# How long does it take to sync Rinkeby network with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ethereumjs, rinkeby, geth-debugging

I am syncing the Rinkeby network with geth

`geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath="~/.ethereum/geth.ipc"`

When I run

`eth syncing`

in geth console, it is showing

```
{
  currentBlock: 1977672,
  highestBlock: 3290356,
  knownStates: 4267080,
  pulledStates: 4265773,
  startingBlock: 1254995
}
```

Is there any approximate time to complete syncing?

After syncing the first time, should I go through the same process next time? Or I can sync in less time than the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time varies from computer to computer, since it depends on the hardware on each one. However, it is usual that syncing from block 0 is (relatively) faster that catching up to a previously synced blockchain. You can see in the geth output how many blocks are imported each time, however, states are other thing, and, as far as I know, there is no way of knowing how many states are currently on any chain.

Comment: If i completed syncing once, should I go for the whole syncing process second time?

Comment: It really depends on how much syncing is needed, i don't have a benchmark on _when_ exactly that is, but in your case, i doubt it would be necesary